# How do I call the properties correctly after using JSONDecoder

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm decoding a JSON, then I created a completionHandler function to be able to get the JSON parsed properties wherever I want in the project. However, when I call the function and print just the property I want, I got all of them together instead of the property called.

For example: I call beer.name, so when I print it out I got all the properties and values containing in my decoded Struct. What am I doing wrong? I need to get these values separated to be able to populate a UITableView and also other components.

***ViewController***

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getApiData { (cerveja) in
            for beer in cerveja {
                print(beer.name!)
            } 
        }
    }
```

> That's what I got for this call below:

```
[HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Buzz"), abv: 4.5, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Trashy Blonde"), abv: 4.1, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/2.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Berliner Weisse With Yuzu - B-Sides"), abv: 4.2, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Pilsen Lager"), abv: 6.3, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/4.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Avery Brown Dredge"), abv: 7.2, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/5.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Electric India"), abv: 5.2, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/6.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("AB:12"), abv: 11.2, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/7.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Fake Lager"), abv: 4.7, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/8.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("AB:07"), abv: 12.5, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/9.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Bramling X"), abv: 7.5, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/10.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Misspent Youth"), abv: 7.3, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Arcade Nation"), abv: 5.3, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/12.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Movember"), abv: 4.5, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/13.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Alpha Dog"), abv: 4.5, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/14.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Mixtape 8"), abv: 14.5, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/15.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Libertine Porter"), abv: 6.1, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/16.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("AB:06"), abv: 11.2, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/17.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Russian Doll – India Pale Ale"), abv: 6.0, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/18.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Hello My Name Is Mette-Marit"), abv: 8.2, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/19.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Rabiator"), abv: 10.27, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Vice Bier"), abv: 4.3, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Devine Rebel (w/ Mikkeller)"), abv: 12.5, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/22.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Storm"), abv: 8.0, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/23.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("The End Of History"), abv: 55.0, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/24.png"), HakerRank___Bruno_Vavretchek.Cerveja(name: Optional("Bad Pixie"), abv: 4.7, image_url: "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/25.png")]
```

*What I needed indeed would be all names or abv's or image_url's*

***Model Folder:***

```
struct Cerveja:Decodable{
    let name:String?
    let abv:Double
    let image_url:String
}
```

***Networking Folder:***

```
func getApiData(completion: @escaping ([Cerveja]) -> ()){
    guard let urlString = URL(string: "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers") else {
        print("URL Error")
        return
    }
    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in

        if response.data == response.data{
            do{
                let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode([Cerveja].self, from: response.data!)
                print(decoder)
            }catch{
        print(error)
            }
        }else{print("API Response is Empty")}

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you are printing "decoder". You have to write this:

```
func getApiData(completion: @escaping ([Cerveja]) -> ()){
guard let urlString = URL(string: "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers") else {
    print("URL Error")
    return
}
Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in

    if let data = response.data{
        do{
            let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode([Cerveja].self, from: data)
            completion(decoder)
        }catch{
    print(error)
        }
    }else{print("API Response is Empty")}

    }
```

}

Avoid you forceUnwraps. So use

```
if let data = response.data{ 
   // Some code
}
```

Then you can print it in viewDidLoad()

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getApiData { (cerveja) in
        for beer in cerveja {
            print(beer.name!)
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current attached log is from

```
print(decoder)
```

not from the for loop , comment it and try , you don't even return the completion

```
func getApiData(completion: @escaping ([Cerveja]) -> ()){
    guard let urlString = URL(string: "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers") else {
        print("URL Error")
        return
    }
    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in

        if response.data == response.data{
            do{
                let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode([Cerveja].self, from: response.data!)
               // print(decoder)

                completion(decoder) // here 

            }
            catch{
                 print(error)
            }
        }else{print("API Response is Empty")}

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of your model>

```
 var arrBeer: [Cerveja]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getApiData { (cerveja) in

     arrBeer = cerveja // you save all your model objects in this array
    }
}
```

Now ready to use your controller and use in tableView cell.

```
let model = arrBeer[indexPath.row]
cell.name = model.name
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hello! Man, your code looks very clean and would be very nice for me if everything works perfectly. However, I got a 0 objects count on my UITableView methods.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments!! Definitely it works, If you saved your model objects in the array. finger cross :)